# Nexus Repository Manager not finding pom file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

I am looking for the pom file: org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.11.M2 - this pom is available at http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.11.M2/aspectjrt-1.6.11.M2.pom.

How do I get nexus to fetch this pom?

I have added the repository http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/ to the public group. This repo does not expose a nexus index.

I am using eclipse with maven configured to point to my local nexus repository in the recommended fashion but eclipse an m2eclipse keep saying: 2011/04/18 1:34:59 PM: [WARN] The POM for org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.11.M2 is missing, no dependency information available

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the corresponding directory (org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.6.11.M2) from you local m2 directory (not from the nexus), and then try it again.

Comment: that fixed some of the other anomalies I was having but hasn't resolved my specific problem

Comment: @Michael Wiles: And the other dependencies from the same repository work?

Comment: as far as I can tell, none of the dependencies work. Artifactory appears to have the same problem.

Comment: and I think it has to do with the fact that artifactory/nexus are not able to proxy/virtualise repositories that do not offer indexing. Looks like they have decided to not simply try and load stuff from every repository that is virtualised. Maven though, AFAIK does do this. Maybe it's a configuration on nexus that I'm missing